# Package created with setuptools with dependencies specified in pyproject.toml, dependencies not being installed

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I'm creating a python package according to the guide here https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html. All project metadata, including dependencies is specified in `pyproject.toml`. This should work as far as I can see from the setuptools documentation. My project does not have a setup.py file. However when I install the package with pip, none of the dependencies are installed. Examining the wheel package, there are no dependencies specified in the METADATA file. What did I miss?

I'm trying to install with pip 22.0

My pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>= 40.9.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
   name="myproject"
#    dynamic = ["version", "readme"]
   description='This is myproject'
   readme = "README.md"
   license = {text = "All rights reserved. Internal use only"}
   requires-python = ">=3.7"
   version = "1.8.10.post4"
   [authors]
       name= "me"
       email = "me@example.com"
   urls = ["https://self-hosted-gitlab/myproject/myproject"]

   classifiers = [
       "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7"
   ]

   dependencies = [
       "pyqt5-stubs == 5.14.2.2",
       "pandas",
       "numpy >= 1.16",
       "matplotlib >=3.1.1",
       "dill",
       "progressbar2",
       "appdirs",
       "tables",
       "seaborn",
       "psutil >=5.6.3",
       "openpyxl == 3.0.1",
       "pywin32; platform_system=='Windows'",
       "wxpython == 4.1.1",
       "ipython",
       "setuptools",
       "packaging",
       "networkx",
       "pyyaml",
       "xlrd",
       "addcopyfighandler",
       "cloudpickle",
       "yccloudpickle",
       "spyder-kernels == 2.1.*",
       "pyqt5",
       "configparser",
       "sympy",
       "termcolor"
   ]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["myproject"]

#[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
#where = [""]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"*" = ["import_settings_default.yaml", "instrument_type_codes.yaml", "default_config.yaml"]

[tool.setuptools.exclude-package-data]
"*" = ["*.bak", "*.wxg", "*.pkl"]
```

Comment: Did the answer you got resolve this? I have the same issue I think and upgrading everything did not work for me.

Comment: I don't think an upgrade totally fixed it for me. But I got busy with other things and never looked into it further. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until I upgraded setuptools, `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. That took me from 58.1.0 to 65.1 and my dependencies started working.